# How can I add aria-label to selectize.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

So selectize.js just ignores the original input field and creates its own and therefore the original label now isn't associated with the new input.

I would like to add an aria-label to the new selectize.js field for screen readers.

Anyone know how to modify the html attributes selectize puts on its inputs?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know but ran into the exact same question. The W3C has a list of requirements for an autocomplete that this is soooooooo close to meeting.
http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#autocomplete

Comment: For those with the same question, @AndyBean created a corresponding issue: [Aria accessibility just lacking](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/issues/798)

Answer (score 2):

**Use a custom plugin and a hidden label for screen readers**

You can override most behavior in plugins for SelectizeJS, and in this case one idea is to override the option and item (selection) rendering methods to add ARIA roles tags for support.

You can also use a "visuallyhidden" class to hide the label visually if you want but it still be noticeable to screen readers. In the plugin you can also associate the label you make with the $control_input (the new input) Selectize creates on initialization. Specifically, set the **aria-labelledby** attribute to associate the input with some label.

**CSS**

```
.visuallyhidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h4>SelectizeJS&nbsp;&nbsp;<small></smmall>Simple Aria Plugin</small></h4>
    <hr />
    <form id="select">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="visuallyhidden" id="selectizeLabel"><strong>Example: Roles and Labels</strong></label><br />
        <label id="selectizeLabel"><strong>Example: Roles and Labels</strong></label><br />
        <select id="wiki-select-property" class="form-control"></select>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**Plugin JavaScript**

```
Selectize.define('simple_aria', function(options) {
  options = $.extend({
    append_to_option: options.append_to_option || true,
    append_to_item: options.append_to_item || true
  }, options);

  var simpleListBoxAria = function(thisRef, options) {
    var self = thisRef;

     thisRef.setup = (function() {
       var original = self.setup;

       return function() {
         // SET REFERENCE: original rendering methods
         var render_item   = self.settings.render.item;
         var render_option = self.settings.render.option;

         // OVERRIDE [selection] rendering-method
         if (options.append_to_item) {
           self.settings.render.item   = function(data, escape) {
              var item_html = '<span class="selectize-selection" aria-selected="true">';
              item_html += render_item.apply(self, arguments);
              item_html += '</span>';
              return item_html;
           };
         }

         // OVERRIDE [option] rendering-method
         if (options.append_to_option) {
           self.settings.render.option = function(data, escape) {
            var option_html = "<div class='option' role='option'>";
            option_html += escape(data.title);
            option_html += "</div>";
            return option_html;
           };
         }

         original.apply(self, arguments);

         // ADD AriaRole for Selectize Select
         thisRef.$control_input.attr('role', 'listbox');
         thisRef.$control_input.attr('aria-labelledby', 'selectizeLabel');
       }
     })();
  }

  simpleListBoxAria(this, options);
  return;
}); // END aria plugin
```

[Here's a Plnkr link to demonstrate all together](https://plnkr.co/edit/ovWIbe?p=preview)

And a good reference for Select widgets and accessibility, [ARIA ListBox in Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/listbox_role)